# How to get Sage 50 Api key and secret

Tags: sage-erp, sage50

I am new to the sage 50 and not able to find any proper documentation on this. I have created account in sage 50 also registered developer and have developerId and applicationId. According to this documentation "http://qa-developer-portal-50cloud.sageaccountantscloud.com/how-to/" created passcode but not able to find the option in account to use this passcode.

Answer (score 0):

The passcode needs to be entered into the Sage 50Cloud application in:

**Settings->Sage Data Integration Settings->Add Integration**

This should then send a call back to your application if you have registered the callback url or an email to your developer account if you have not.